# two dropdown menus to be processed by 3 dimensional array to determine a price

Tags: php, html

i have been spending the entire weekend on this but cannot seem to get it solved.

My html consists of two drop down menus. One determines a specific type and the second determines a component.

There is predefined costs associated with each component based on the type its being used for.

Here my HTML:

```
 <td><select name="type">
<option value= "0" selected>None</option>
<option value = "CAR">Car</option>
<option value = "VAN">Van</option>
<option value = "TRK">Truck</option>
</select></td>

<td>Component:</td>
<td><select name="component">
<option value= "0" selected>None</option>
<option value = "TIR">Oil</option>
<option value = "OIL">Tire</option>
<option value = "SPK">Spark Plug</option>
</select></td>
```

My php looks like this:

```
$cat = array(
'CAR_TIR' => array('comp' => 'Tires','price' => 100),
'CAR_OIL' => array('comp' => 'Oil', 'price' => 10),
'CAR_SPK' => array('comp' => 'Spark Plug', 'price' => 4),

'VAN_TIR' => array('comp' => 'Tires','price' => 120),
 'VAN_OIL' => array('comp' => 'Oil', 'price' =>12),
      'VAN_SPK' => array('comp' => 'Spark Plug', 'price' =>5),

'TRK_TIR' => array('comp' => 'Tires','price' => 150),
'TRK_OIL' => array('comp' => 'OIL','price' => 15),
'TRK_SPK' => array('comp' => 'Tires','price' => 6),

);
echo $cat[$_POST['type'].'_'.$_POST['component']]['price']; 
?>
```

and the output that i am getting looks like this :
Price checkup?
array('comp' => 'Tires','price' => 100), 'CAR_OIL' => array('comp' => 'Oil', 'price' => 10), 'CAR_SPK' => array('comp' => 'Spark Plug', 'price' => 4), 'VAN_TIR' => array('comp' => 'Tires','price' => 120), 'VAN_OIL' => array('comp' => 'Oil', 'price' =>12), 'VAN_SPK' => array('comp' => 'Spark Plug', 'price' =>5), 'TRK_TIR' => array('comp' => 'Tires','price' => 150), 'TRK_OIL' => array('comp' => 'OIL','price' => 15), 'TRK_SPK' => array('comp' => 'Tires','price' => 6), ); echo $cat[$*POST['type'].'*'.$_POST['component']]['price']; ?>

so literally that is the output. please let me know what i could do. thanks!

Comment: please post the code that is generating the output above

Comment: when i hit submit the very last part is what is being shown on my page: Price checkup? array('comp' => 'Tires','price' => 100), 'CAR_OIL' => array('comp' => 'Oil', 'price' => 10), 'CAR_SPK' => array('comp' => 'Spark Plug', 'price' => 4), 'VAN_TIR' => etc. in other words there is no processing whatsoever.

Comment: please post the part of the code that is producing this output.

Comment: please consider to accept an answer (click tick mark on the left) if it actually answered your question

Answer (score 0):

Is a three dimensional array necessary? It seems like a very messy and hard to read way of doing things to me. Three arrays would be easier to read I would think, if possible?

Write three separate arrays to show the dropdowns (try `foreach` instead of a `for` loop) then use the values of each to calculate the price after it has been submitted.

If this is not what you're looking for then you'll have to clarify your questions a little better. :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response John.

Answer (score 0):

You should use nested associative arrays instead of numerical. An associative array is one which it's elements are referenced by a string instead of a number. This should make referencing each element much easier.

For your case, you should use something like:

```
$categories = array( 
    'car' => array( 'oil' => 10, 'spark' => 10 ),
    'van' => array( 'oil' => 12, 'spark' => 12 ),
    'truck' => array( 'oil'=> 15, 'spark' => 15 )
);
```

And to get the selected item from the form, you can just do this:

```
$type = $_POST['type'];
$component = $_POST['component'];
// Error check $type and $component
$selected = $categories[$type][$component];
```

Don't forget to change your html `option` values from integers to strings which match the array keys. You'll also need to change your for loops to [foreach loops.](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 0):

why not go by two dimensions, and an associative array, which I find easier to read:

```
<td>Car type:</td>
<td><select name="type">
    <option value= "0" selected>None</option>
    <option value = "CAR">Car</option>
    <option value = "VAN">Van</option>
    <option value = "TRK">Truck</option>
</select></td>

<td>Component:</td>
<td><select name="component">
    <option value= "0" selected>None</option>
    <option value = "TIR">Oil</option>
    <option value = "OIL">Tire</option>
    <option value = "SPK">Spark Plug</option>
</select></td>

$cat = array(
    'CAR_TIR' => array('comp' => 'Tires','price' => 100),
    'CAR_OIL' => array('comp' => 'Oil', 'price' => 10),
    'CAR_SPK' => array('comp' => 'Spark Plug', 'price' => 4),
    'VAN_TIR' => array('comp' => 'Tires','price' => 200),
    'TRK_TIR' => array('comp' => 'Tires','price' => 300)
    ); // fill in the missing values for VAN and TRK
```

Referencing:

```
echo $cat['CAR_TIR']['comp']; // output: Tires
echo $cat['CAR_TIR']['price']; // output: 100
echo $cat['TRK_TIR']['price']; // output: 300
```

Referencing with input from form (assuming `type` and `component` are set):

```
echo $cat[$_POST['type'].'_'.$_POST['component']]['price']; 
// type='CAR', component='OIL', Output: 10
```

Looping:

```
foreach ($cat as $key => $value) {
    echo 'Code: '.$key.', component: '.$value['comp'].', price:'.$value['price'];
}
```

Comment: Ok i change it and the Html looks like this:                                                                      <td>Car type:</td>
<td><select name="type">
    <option value= "0" selected>None</option>
    <option value = "CAR">Car</option>
    <option value = "VAN">Van</option>
    <option value = "TRK">Truck</option>
</select></td>

<td>Component:</td>
<td><select name="component">
    <option value= "0" selected>None</option>
    <option value = "TIR">Oil</option>
    <option value = "OIL">Tire</option>
    <option value = "SPK">Spark Plug</option>
</select></td>

Comment: php:$cat = array(
    'CAR_TIR' => array('comp' => 'Tires','price' => 100),
    'CAR_OIL' => array('comp' => 'Oil', 'price' => 10),
    'CAR_SPK' => array('comp' => 'Spark Plug', 'price' => 4),
    
    'VAN_TIR' => array('comp' => 'Tires','price' => 120),
     'VAN_OIL' => array('comp' => 'Oil', 'price' =>12),
          'VAN_SPK' => array('comp' => 'Spark Plug', 'price' =>5),

    'TRK_TIR' => array('comp' => 'Tires','price' => 150),
    'TRK_OIL' => array('comp' => 'OIL','price' => 15),
    'TRK_SPK' => array('comp' => 'Tires','price' => 6),
    
    );

?>
but its still not working..

Comment: @user2085307: what exactly is not working? what do you get? please edit your question and post your code there, nicer to read :-)

Comment: :) ok sorry. im totally confused here and the frustration is rising. thanks again ill try to make it more readable

Comment: @user2085307: no problem ;-) just tell us what you want to accomplish, we'll support you.

Comment: what i need is to display it like this: car type (whatever the input from drop down menu will be chosen) and then component (whatever is also chosen) and then the price in the last line which needs to be determined by the two choices made from the user.